# Verify in-app purchase in App Store on server side

Tags: .net, in-app-purchase, app-store, deprecated

I want to verify in-app purchases on the .net server side

As I researched the **/verifyReceipt** endpoint of [App Store Server API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi) is deprecated - doc: [Validating receipts with the App Store](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store)

Then if I want to verify an in-app purchase, using the library [App Store Server Library](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/simplifying_your_implementation_by_using_the_app_store_server_library) is required

This library only supports 4 languages (Swift, Java, Python, Node), my server has been built by **.Net** though.
I have an idea to build another service running Node to use this library, yet this will consume a lot of effort.

Please give me a solution if you have the same issue as me. Any comment is appreciated.